# Typescript error with React (div element)

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I faced the following error when I send the remaining props, (`...props`) to a `<div>` element. I tried several solutions but didn't succeed.

> React.createElement

with casting?

```
Error:(35, 10) TS2322: Type '{ children: ReactNode; defaultChecked?: boolean | undefined; defaultValue?: string | number | readonly string[] | undefined; suppressContentEditableWarning?: boolean | undefined; ... 249 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: ((event: TransitionEvent<...>) => void) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  Type '{ children: ReactNode; defaultChecked?: boolean | undefined; defaultValue?: string | number | readonly string[] | undefined; suppressContentEditableWarning?: boolean | undefined; ... 249 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: ((event: TransitionEvent<...>) => void) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property ''aria-relevant'' are incompatible.
      Type '"text" | "additions" | "additions removals" | "additions text" | "all" | "removals" | "removals additions" | "removals text" | "text additions" | "text removals" | undefined' is not assignable to type '"text" | "additions" | "additions text" | "all" | "removals" | undefined'.
        Type '"additions removals"' is not assignable to type '"text" | "additions" | "additions text" | "all" | "removals" | undefined'.
```

The code:

```
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

type Direction = 'row' | 'column';

interface FlexProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
    direction?: Direction;
    reverse?: boolean;
    inline?: boolean;
}

const Flex: FunctionComponent<FlexProps> = (
    {
        direction = 'row',
        reverse = false,
        inline = false,
        ...props
    }: FlexProps
): JSX.Element => {
    const flex: string = inline ? 'inline-flex' : 'flex';

    const directionReverse: string = [
      'flex',
      direction,
      reverse && 'reverse'
    ].join('-');

    const className: string = classNames(
        flex,
        directionReverse,
        props.className
    );

    return (
        <div className={className} {...props}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I have already tried with:

```
DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>
```

Comment: Your Flex component looks good.. I just copy it and worked for me. What are you doing to get this error? Didn't get it quite well.... (I just did this `<Flex>Test</Flex>` )

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto  when I want to test my component I have this error or when I run typecript "tsc"

Comment: Same for me, everything works just fine. Perhaps, check the versions of the typings that you use?

Comment: I suspect, the issue is not with component definition, but rather with its usage, - somewhere out there, there's the code `<Flex aria-relevant="additions removals">`

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - use `aria-relevant="all"` instead.

---

There's a code in your app that might look like this

```
<Flex ... aria-relevant="additions removals">...</Flex>
```

You can find it by searching globally on your project with regex:

```
<Flex(.|\n)*?aria-relevant="additions removals"
```

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-relevant_attribute):

> A space-delimited list of one or more of the following values:
>
> - `additions` Element nodes added to the accessibility tree within the live region; should be considered relevant.
> - `removals` are deletion of nodes in the accessiblity tree; should be considered relevant.
> - `text` are changes to the textual content of existing nodes; should be considered relevant.
> - `all` is equivalent to additions removals text.
> - `aria-relevant="additions text"` is the default value on a live region.

In your case, you may want to use `all` instead of your current value (`additions removals`) This is equivalent to additions removals text and it's a valid, what I can't say about the value "additions removals".

Comment: Thanks, 

Information about aria-relevant -> https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/47012

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you are not very familiar with `TypeScript` in `ReactJS`, Even you don't know about the `rest` of destructuring `props` in `ReactJS`, the `div` JSX will transform to read `<div>` HTML element by ReactDOM, so you should care about every passing prop because every prop will transform to HTML Attribute, so passing `rest` to is a fault, I mean:

```js
~~~ ({
 somePropName,
 ...rest
}) => (
  <div {...rest} // -- this passing rest is a fault
```

*And about `TypeScript` in `ReactJS`, I really offer you to buy **Maximilian Schwarzmüller**, TypeScript training, and especially study the ReactJS module.*

By the way, the right way of writing of your component is the below code:

```js
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';

interface FlexProps {
  direction?: 'row' | 'column';
  reverse?: boolean;
  inline?: boolean;
  children: ReactNode;
  className: string;
}

const Flex: FC<FlexProps> = ({
  direction = 'row',
  reverse,
  inline,
  className,
  children,
}) => {
  const flex: string = inline ? 'inline-flex' : 'flex';

  const directionReverse: string = [
    'flex',
    direction,
    reverse && 'reverse',
  ].join('-');

  const classNames: string = cn(flex, directionReverse, className);

  return <div className={classNames}>{children}</div>;
};

export default Flex;
```

Why you pass a default *false* value to the `boolean` prop?? when a developer(even you) use your `Flex` component and do not pass a boolean prop, so it will be `undefined` and by the JavaScript, the `coercion` will happen and the value will be a _false` boolean value.

Instead of type `JSX.Element` pass a regular `TypeScirpt-React` valid type, hence, `ReactNode`, easy.

Also by using `FC<FlexProps>` there is no need to have `}: FlexProps) => {` only the `}) => {` is enough.

If in future a new prop name will be needed, Ok, add it to the interface and use it in the component but do not pass a `rest` of props. it is not a valid way in ReactJS development.